Custom Cursor Stuck on Interactive Elements like Links/Buttons
I'm implementing a custom cursor consisting of two elements: a small black dot and a larger trailing transparent circle. While it works globally, the issue arises when hovering over interactive elements like links or buttons. The custom cursor freezes at the edge of these elements, and the default hand pointer appears instead.
<style>
  body {
    cursor: none;
  }
  .cursor {
    position: fixed;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #2f2f2f;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 10000;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  .cursor-follower {
    position: fixed;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: rgba(232, 226, 223, 0.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  a {
    cursor: none;
  }
</style>
<div class="cursor"></div>
<div class="cursor-follower"></div>
<script>
  const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
  const follower = document.querySelector('.cursor-follower');
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    cursor.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
    cursor.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
  });
</script>


What I Tried:
I implemented a custom cursor using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. The cursor consists of two elements: a small black dot and a larger trailing circle. I used pointer-events: none and cursor: none globally to disable the default cursor. However, when hovering over interactive elements like links or buttons, the custom cursor freezes at the edge, and the default hand pointer appears.
Any guidance is appreciated!

Better define the cursor styling within the body CSS property. So it automatically applies throughout the project. You can always assign an image as your custom cursor via cursor: url(your-img-path). If that doesn't work; explicitly define the cursor property within the button & a properties in CSS to have the same image value. Let me know if it helps

Instead of removing cursor on the body, remove it for everything.
* {
  cursor: none;
}

